# Borderlands 2 lost save character Playstation 3

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recover a lost Borderlands 2 game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85294/how-do-i-recover-a-lost-borderlands-2-game)

I started a single player game with 'assassin' and levelled up to 13. I then selected new game and began a multiplayer with a friend, both with my original name 1-Jebadeeoo 2- Jebadeedoo(1).

I saved and quit this mission. My original single player game with assassin level 13 has disappeared and is no longer accessible, and although the saved game still shows up in the 'saved game utility' on the PlayStation home menu I cannot access it in the game.

Can you tell me how I can access this game file, as the only game I can 'continue' on is the more recent multiplayer save.

Comment: There should be a "Select Character" option on the first screen.  That will allow you to switch which character you're playing.