# If I save and quit, does it save for teammates?

Tags: borderlands-2

If I "Save and Quit" by using the PAUSE menu, does it also save for my co-op partners/other players in my game that I'm hosting?
[image: quitting hosting]
Or does it only save for me when I quit but not others' progress? Is it effectively like they Save and Quit too or is it effectively like their game crashes relative to their character data, lost and unsaved?

Answer (score 5):

Mission progress is based on the host. The progress of joined players will not save to their single player play-through. They can keep their character progression and any loot.

Comment: So you're saying if I host someone from the beginning of the game to the end then quit, their story will still be at the beginning? That also doesn't answer my question. I'm asking about if it saves when the host quits, not particularly about missions.

Comment: They do answer the question, even with your edits. The only part that may be unclear is "character progression" they keep their levels and talents along with loot, but like they said, their story line is still at the start.

Comment: @NiteCyper That is an answer to your question. The story progress for the other players will not save for them and they will remain at the beginning. It's all dependent of the host and the story the host is working on. The levels gained and the loot earned however remain.

Comment: "The progress of joined players will not save to their single player play-through." This doesn't seem to be true as per [How does mission progress work in multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85136/4797)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a big deal if you're worried about others if you as the host quit.

The game saves everyone's progress at each auto-save points (fast travel stations, spawn point markers, major mission completions, etc), which you run across fairly often. So even if it doesn't save at the very last moment of the disconnect, it still saved for them recently during the last checkpoint you had. (I've also never noticed anything missing ever when hosts quit on me; so I think it does a Save and Quit for them too, but I haven't checked for millisecond timing on it. I just know definitively that it saves at auto-points very regularly.)

Keep in mind, *what* is saved gets a little tricky. Experience, loot, skill choices are all saved at each auto-save point. @Ryan suggested that mission progress isn't saved, which isn't entirely true. It saves mission completions if an entire mission is run from start to finish during the session and the mission wasn't completed before but was available—if it was in your mission log first or not can affect things too. And it gets more complicated for the plot missions depending if you've completed it or not... or a few other scenarios can affect it. But that's another topic for another [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85136/1134).

The main point is: don't worry about it. Enough will get saved for them as you were all running past all the auto-saves and respawns, it'll be fine. At most they may miss a handful of XP and such if you drop the host connection without Save and Quit.

(But if you want to be extra safe though, maybe don't drop the connection *immediately* after a big boss takedown—just to be safe. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the host uses the Save and Quit option, it saves for other players too. As in it triggers a save. I do not think that if a non-host uses the Save and Quit option that it saves for others.